# OpenAI speech to text API not giving correct timestamp in vtt file

Tags: openai-api, openai-whisper

I am using OpenAI speech to text API to generate captions in the form of a vtt file. There are other response format supported as well like json, verbose_json, text, srt and vtt.
https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio/create

When I am generating the vtt file, the timestamps against the segments are not according to the silence. Even if the voice starts from 10th second, the starting timestamp is 0th second.
The next segment's starting timestamp is the last segment's ending timestamp, irrespective of any silence in between.

How can we handle this? Is there any word timestamps also supported?